# jQuery Submit is posting multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to submit a form that is loaded through a modal dynamically but i have a problem with multiple submissions.  This Code is posting multiple times, can someone explain why?  Thank you.

```
var convArrToObj = function(array){
    var thisEleObj = new Object();
    if(typeof array == "object"){
        for(var i in array){
            var thisEle = convArrToObj(array[i]);
            thisEleObj[i] = thisEle;
        }
    }else {
        thisEleObj = array;
    }
    return thisEleObj;
};
var serialize = function(obj) {
    var str = [];
    for(var p in obj)
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        }
    return str.join("&");
};
var events = [];
var appointments = [];
var formData = [];
$('#newAppointment').on('click', function(){
    $( ".modal-content" ).load( "api/calendar/appointment.php", { personId: $(this).attr('personId')}, function(){
        $(".chosen-select").chosen({width:'100%',placeholder_text_multiple:'Select People'});
        $(".datepicker").pickadate({format: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
        $(".timepicker").pickatime({format: 'HH:i' });
    });
});
$('#page-wrapper').on('mouseenter', '#appointform', function(){
    $('#appointSubmit').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#appointSubmit').prop('disabled',true);
        $("#appointform select").each(function() {
            var fieldName = $(this).attr("name");
            var fieldVal = $(this).val();
            if(typeof fieldVal === 'undefined'){
                fieldVal = "";
            }
            if(! fieldVal ){
                fieldVal = "";
            }
            if($(this).val() === "? undefined:undefined ?"){
                fieldVal = "";
            } 
            formData[fieldName] = fieldVal;
        });
        $("#appointform input").each(function() {
            formData[this.name] = this.value;
        });
        $("#appointform textarea").each(function() {
            formData[this.name] = this.value;
        });
        $('#modal').modal('hide');
        $.post('api/calendar/post', convArrToObj(formData), function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: shot in the dark without seeing html, but is it possible you have the submit function bound twice? perhaps to the form and the button?  else, when you say multiple, is that twice per click or more?

Comment: it submits 3-4 times, every time `mouseenter` fires

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time the mouse enters your `#page-wrapper` element, you're re-binding the click event to `#appointSubmit`, causing the event to fire multiple times when the user clicks the button / link only once.

Comment: so how would i get the jquery to execute on the dynamic content without having the form submit multiple times?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle of your page or some HTML snippets?

Comment: Sorry, just read the bit about `#appointSubmit` not existing on document ready. Bind the click event on the parent element that already exists, and use a selector to filter the event for specific children. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/bc9hjrqs/ - `#child` would be `#appointSubmit` in your case.

Comment: I actually just added `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` after you pointed out that it was rebinding every time, which worked.  Marked your response as the answer since you pointed it out in the first place. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The mouseenter event is likely firing multiple times.  Every time your mouse enters or re-enters the form, it is re-adding the event handler to the form.  You should set the onsubmit/onclick handler for your button once in the load callback function instead to prevent this from happening.

Comment: this actually doesn't work, the problem is i have to delegate the jquery to an element that is there on document ready and then give it instructions to look for a child dom element. unfortunately that seems to be what causes the multiple submitting

Answer (score 1):

Remove `mouseenter` listener you really don't need it.

```
var convArrToObj = function(array){
        var thisEleObj = new Object();
        if(typeof array == "object"){
            for(var i in array){
                var thisEle = convArrToObj(array[i]);
                thisEleObj[i] = thisEle;
            }
        }else {
            thisEleObj = array;
        }
        return thisEleObj;
    };
    var serialize = function(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for(var p in obj)
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
            }
        return str.join("&");
    };
    var events = [];
    var appointments = [];
    var formData = [];
    $('#newAppointment').on('click', function(){
        $( ".modal-content" ).load( "api/calendar/appointment.php", { personId: $(this).attr('personId')}, function(){
            $(".chosen-select").chosen({width:'100%',placeholder_text_multiple:'Select People'});
            $(".datepicker").pickadate({format: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
            $(".timepicker").pickatime({format: 'HH:i' });
        });
    });
        $('#appointSubmit').on('click', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#appointSubmit').prop('disabled',true);
            $("#appointform select").each(function() {
                var fieldName = $(this).attr("name");
                var fieldVal = $(this).val();
                if(typeof fieldVal === 'undefined'){
                    fieldVal = "";
                }
                if(! fieldVal ){
                    fieldVal = "";
                }
                if($(this).val() === "? undefined:undefined ?"){
                    fieldVal = "";
                } 
                formData[fieldName] = fieldVal;
            });
            $("#appointform input").each(function() {
                formData[this.name] = this.value;
            });
            $("#appointform textarea").each(function() {
                formData[this.name] = this.value;
            });
            $('#modal').modal('hide');
            $.post('api/calendar/post', convArrToObj(formData), function(response){
                console.log(response);
            });
    });
```

Comment: why do i not need it? The jquery doesn't work if i remove `mouseenter` because the element `#appointSubmit` doesnt exist in the dom on document ready